# Javascript regex replace using $ with WebKit

Tags: javascript, regex, webkit, replace

Using $ to match end-of-input gives a zero-length match everywhere else but no evidence of a match with WebKit:

```
function showBug() {
  Result = "the end.".replace( /(end\.)([\s]|$)?/img, makeChange );
  return;
  }
function makeChange() {
  for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 1 ) {
    document.write( "arg" + i + " -->" + arguments[ i ] + "<--"  + "<BR>" );
    }
  }
```

gives

```
arg0 -->end.<--
arg1 -->end.<--
arg2 -->undefined<--
arg3 -->4<--
arg4 -->the end.<--
```

for `AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.5 Safari/534.55.3`, 
also for `AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19`.

Opera (`Presto/2.10.229 Version/11.62`), FF (`Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2`) and IE (`MSIE 8.0; Trident/4.0`) all give

```
arg0 -->end.<--
arg1 -->end.<--
arg2 --><--
arg3 -->4<--
arg4 -->the end.<--
```

which means I can detect the match in $2 (it's actually about interpreting a trailing dot on a url as not being part of the url). I'm currently adding a trailing space for WebKit, and taking it off afterwards, but I'm wondering if anyone has a better solution and can confirm I should raise this as a bug.

Comment: What happens if you remove the "?" from the regular expression?

Comment: First, you don't need the `|` in that expression. So you could write it `/(end\.)([\s])?$/` to match something before end-of-line. Second, are you trying to match 0 or 1 of 's' and '\' or are you trying to match whitespace `\s` (no brackets)? http://jsfiddle.net/2hZdT/

Comment: I just tested here in Chrome and it works.

Comment: var t = "the end.".replace( /(end\.)([\s]|$)+/img, "###"); the value of "t" is "the ###"

Comment: @JohnFisher Good idea, that makes WebKit show a match occurred. But now the regex doesn't do what I want i.e. find a dot with at least one space after else eoi.

Comment: @Mathletics I maybe over-simplified my code to make a demo of the problem. I'm wanting to find dots in url path/query/fragments with either a space after or eoi, so I can interpret the dot as a natural language full stop instead of a char in the url.

Comment: @anweald: How is that?  The "?" makes the space or eol optional, while taking it out makes it required...

Comment: @RodrigoManguinho Thanks, do you have a Chrome build#?

Comment: @RodrigoManguinho Yes the match happens OK, I want to detect it in the makeChange function when there's no char involved, because I need to do nerdy things to extend what regexes can't do.

Comment: @JohnFisher There may not be one, e.g. `Result = "the end.abc".replace( /(end\.)([\s]|$)?/img, makeChange );` will tell `makeChange()` not to consider interpreting the dot.

Comment: @anweald:  I think you're misunderstanding the regex you posted.  "\.([\s]|$)?" should match all of these strings: ".a", ".", ". ".  Since "?" makes "([\s]|$)" optional, the ".a" works, too.  (Unless you have some sort of weird regex implementation.)

Comment: @JohnFisher I think I've not made a clear question. It's not about what gets matched - the matching works fine - it's about what gets passed through in $2. Webkit gives the same thing ("undefined") if there's no match for the ([\s]|$) as when there is a match and it's down to the $. The former is what you'd expect, my makeChange code doesn't start interpreting the dot. The latter is different cross-browser. Maybe I'll try making a better demo.

Comment: There's indeed a difference in browser behavior - here's a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/HrMJU/4/ . It's caused by ? - 

".".replace( /(\.)?/) = ".".replace(/(\.)|()/) and as such I'd go with Chrome's undefined value.

however, doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/HrMJU/5/ makes more sense, as $? doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the empty string, you should include the question mark inside the capturing group, e.g.

```
/(end\.)((?:\s|$)?)/
```

The reason is that a group that does not capture anything is not the same thing that a group that captures an empty string. For example, think at what the second parentheses should capture in the following example :

```
/a(b(x))?c/.exec('ac');
```